# using galaxybase-load: "Please enable Data Visualization Service"

Tags: graph-databases

I'm using galaxybase-load to import data into Galaxybase and here is the prompt that I got: Please enable Data Visualization Service. What should I do to continue the importing progress?How can I start the data visulization service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prompt indicates that the data visualization service is not currently started and that the data visualization service needs to be started first in the **51314 page service**.